# "Would something like to do something"?

Tags: grammaticality

We often ask this question: “Would **you** like to do something?”. However, is it grammatically correct to say, “Would *something* like to do something?”  For example:

> *Would IBM like to acquire Apple?*

Comment: In your example, IBM is someone, rather than something

Comment: In the specific example you give, people are more likely to say "Would IBM want to acquire Apple".  In general, it is easier to imagine large organisations as having drives and intentions, as implied by "want", than caprices and whims.

Comment: Why do you think it is correct/acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your example of IBM *acquiring* Apple is correct. *You* is just a placeholder and can be replaced by a person's name, organization, place, etc. Here's an example that may help you wrap your head around it.

> Would *he/she/they/it/I/someone/* like to acquire Apple.

That said, when you refer to an organization, you are actually referring to something that's a living thing and acts more like a body of people working together. So you wouldn't really say,

> Would a stone like to eat something?

This is not ungrammatical, but unidiomatic and to some extent illogical, unless we live in an imaginary world.

Answer (score 1):

***Things*** do not have brains and therefore cannot have preferences. They cannot like or dislike. As Noah said, IBM is functioning as an organism and is capable of making decisions.

Answer (score -6):

No It won't be correct After "Would" a pronoun is required while in the example you are using Noun ("IBM" - Name of a firm).

Comment: This is absolutely, entirely, 100 per cent **incorrect**. A noun (phrase) can function as a subject just as well as a pronoun (which _is_ in fact a noun phrase).

Comment: @Victor: Any reference for you saying so pal?

Comment: I'm wondering: Would Victor like to clarify this answer?

Comment: So it would be wrong to say "Would Mrs Smith like a visit?" ??